# Explain why this was closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/399298/what-is-the-point-of-spam-like-this) asked a specific, meaningful question that presumably has a specific answer.  Why was everyone so quick to pounce on it?

Granted, the question was asked out of academic curiosity rather than a specific "need", that's true of many questions and no reason to close.  I figured someone out there has the expertise to answer the question with modest authority, so it's no more soliciting "opinion" than any other question.

Comment: For what its worth, I got some reasonable answers (and a +4 for the question) on [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12589/what-is-the-point-of-spam-like-this).

Comment: Now it's up to +7.

Comment: Up to +10 and a "Nice Question" badge.

Answer (score 5):

I voted to close as *not constructive*, but you can substitute with *off topic* as well, which would probably better suit the actual question.

- The question is **neither about computer software nor hardware**.
- There's **no specific problem** to solve.

Also, "presumably has a specific answer" is *probably* not enough, and (out of experience) doesn't result in the answers you like to find.

I have to say, it *is* an interesting question, but it is off topic in the scope of our FAQ.

Comment: It seems to me that spam is related to computer software.  And there is a specific problem -- this sort of spam has some purpose, presumably not a good purpose, and knowing that purpose would allow one to better defend against it.

Comment: You never mentioned defending against it. If that's the case and you're talking about forums, maybe [webmasters.SE] is a better home for your question. (But I don't know their FAQ by heart)

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed being `Not Constructive`. Unfortunately, your answer really cannot be accurately answered, and there could be hundreds of reasons why.

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers
>   to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this
>   question **will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or**
>   **extended discussion**. See the FAQ.

Although I think the question itself is great, and I'd love an answer too, we just can't accurately answer it within the scope of Super Users FAQ, without it becoming a problem and generating tons of varying answers that may have little to no facts behind them.

It's unlikely any users here are the makers of these bots, so they can't tell you the reason behind it.

Overall its a great question, but it just isn't for Super User, sorry.

Comment: I don't see how my question was more likely to "solicit opinion, debate", et al than, say [Does Ubuntu Server Edition stable enough for commercial use?](http://superuser.com/questions/48373/does-ubuntu-server-edition-stable-enough-for-commercial-use) (sic).

Comment: (It also seems to me that if the folks here don't understand the reason behind such spams they're at serious risk, if they operate any sort of forum/bulletin-board/blog.)

Comment: @DanH that question is almost 3 years old. The sites FAQ has changed since then.